# Bind "document ready" and "window scroll"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This way I can bind some event to "window load" and "window scroll":

```
$(window).bind('load scroll', function() {
    // ...
});
```

But is there way to bind "document ready" and "window scroll"?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // ...
}

// How to bind them together?
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a function and run the function in both of them?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, I understand. From practical point of view, it is convenient enough, but I trying to learn and discover new ways to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to say you have to define the handler function directly in the call to jQuery - you could easily just define it separately and reuse it.

```
function eventHandler() {
    // Your code goes here
}

$(document).ready(eventHandler);
$(window).on("scroll", eventHandler);
```

jQuery does exactly the same thing (more or less) under the hood for your first example - [they just split the string on whitespace and then run the event registration code once for each](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/625e19cd9be4898939a7c40dbeb2b17e40df9d54/src/event.js#L153).